# How to get the CGRect of the UIScrollView after scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to get the CGRect or just x,y of the area the scrollview currently shows after user has dragged the view when calling `scrollViewDidEndDragging`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current position of UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451969/get-current-position-of-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
scrollView.contentOffset.x 
scrollView.contentOffset.y
```